# C# Multi-Comparisons possible?

Tags: c#

is it possible in some way to compare multiple variables to one constant in a if statement? It would be very helpful if instead of

```
if ( col.Name != "Organization" && col.Name != "Contacts" && col.Name != "Orders" ) { }
```

I could just say

```
if ( col.Name != "Organization" || "Contacts" || "Orders" ) { }
```

And I know I could use a list but in some instances I dont want to... Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're just looking for a shortcut, you probably won't get much. ChaosPandion mentioned the switch statement, and here's something using an array.

```
if (new string[] { "Bar", "Baz", "Blah" }.Contains(foo))
{
    // do something
}
```

Comment: I don't feel you gain very much using this over a switch or if statement.

Comment: It is easier to assert what this code is doing as a human reader and to verify that it is correct as compared to the original question.
(Has no obvious bugs vs obviously has no bugs)

Comment: i like this. functionally of course it doesnt gain anything, ChaosPandion, but as far as readability and clean code i like it personally. of course itd be nice if there was something built into the language rather than so hackish, but still a good solution for now. thanks!

Comment: Clean code? Seems like you unnecessarily just allocated a string array that now has to get garbage collected.

Comment: I would end up using a switch statement most of the time, but am glad to know about it overall as it is interesting and might find use in something else also.

Answer (score 4):

The switch statement is about as good as you'll get.

```
switch (col.Name)
{
    case "Organization":
    case "Contacts":
    case "Orders":
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

Comment: yea. knew about that. but the point was to reduce unneeded code. didnt know if there was a way with Linq or something

Comment: You can use "Linq" in a round about way. In order to implement Linq they needed to add Extension methods. You can use this to your advantage to add methods to string therefore making your code much more concise.

Comment: The most efficient is the most verbose.
How often does that prove to be the "case"?

Answer (score 1):

You could also add extension methods to the string class to make your comparisons less verbose. I'd go with the solution Anthony provides and stick it in an extension methods called EqualsAny or some such.

Answer (score 1):

I second John's comment on extension methods.  I'd do something like this:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static bool In(this string input, params string[] test)
    {
        foreach (var item in test)
            if (item.CompareTo(input) == 0)
                return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

You can then call it like this:

```
        string hi = "foo";
        if (hi.In("foo", "bar")) {
            // Do stuff
        }
```

Comment: Note that you can also uplevel this to an object extension - just change the CompareTo statement to a strict ==

Comment: You could simplify the internals by using `return test.Contains(input);` or `return test.Any(item => item == input);` rather than a foreach loop.

Comment: @Ben Voigt That's true, but if I were doing this with production code, specific to strings, I'd want to use string.Compare instead so I could pass in the appropriate CultureInfo options.  Array.IndexOf doesn't provide that kind of overload since it's designed for any object type.